# ¿Cómo llamar un módulo dentro de un paquete en Python con Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

**CONTEXTO.** Python 3.9.1, Flask 2.0.1

**QUÉ QUIERO HACER.** Llamar un módulo ubicado dentro de un paquete custom.

**PROBLEMA.** No importa lo que haga, la consola insiste en decirme: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mi_paquete'`

**QUÉ ESTOY HACIENDO.** Estoy siguiendo el [tutorial oficial de Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/index.html). Por tanto, la estructura del proyecto básicamente es esta (con ligeros cambios respecto del tutorial):

```
/flask-tutorial
├── flaskr/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── schema.sql
│   ├── templates/
│   ├── static/
│   └── mi_paquete/
│       ├── __init__.py (este archivo está vacío)
│       ├── auth.py
│       ├── backend.py
│       ├── blog.py
│       └── user.py
├── venv/
├── .env
├── .flaskenv
├── setup.py
└── MANIFEST.in
```

Dentro del archivo /flask-tutorial/flaskr/**init**.py intento llamar los módulos que contienen mis blueprints:

```
from mi_paquete import backend
from mi_paquete import auth
from mi_paquete import user
from mi_paquete import blog

backend.bp.register_blueprint(auth.bp)
backend.bp.register_blueprint(user.bp)
backend.bp.register_blueprint(blog.bp)

app.register_blueprint(backend.bp)
```

Al ejecutar la aplicación (con el comando `flask run`), la consola me dice `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mi_paquete'`, indicando que el problema está en la línea donde está `from mi_paquete import backend`.

**CÓMO HE INTENTADO SOLUCIONAR EL PROBLEMA (sin éxito).**

Primero. He creado el archivo el archivo **init**.py vacío dentro de 'mi_paquete', con el fin de que Python tome a la carpeta mi_paquete como un paquete.

Segundo. Dentro del archivo /flask-tutorial/flaskr/**init**.py, antes del FROM problemático, he puesto:

```
import os.path
import sys
parent = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0, parent)
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar esto?

Comment: Cambia `mi_paquete` por `.mi_paquete` (y puedes quitar la parte en que modificas sys.path)

Comment: ¡Por Dios santo! Tienes razón, funciona. No puedo creer que eso sea la respuesta. Muchas gracias, @abulafia.

Comment: Lo del punto se llaman "imports relativos". Funcionan si la carpeta "relativa" es un paquete (es decir, contiene un `__init__.py`), como es tu caso. Por cierto, felicitaciones por una pregunta muy bien planteada.